# ffmpeg "Error reinitializing filters!" on some webm videos

Tags: ffmpeg, image-scaling, webm

I have a dozen of webm videos I need to resize with the following:

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -vf “scale=w=360:h=270:force_original_aspect_ratio=2,fps=10,crop=360:270” output.webm
```

I tried the command and it worked fine for some webm videos, but most of the returned the following error:

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fcb3db076c0] No such filter: '“scale'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
[libopus @ 0x7fcb3c10a000] 1 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

I checked that ffmpeg still worked fine with previously successful files.
How can I get ffmpeg to work with the remaining wemb videos?

Comment: `No such filter: '“scale'` --> replace the fancy double quote with regular ones.

Comment: Thanks @Gyan, the issue was with copy pasting instead on typing directly. both single and double quotes work fine but it seems the app I was using for copy pasting changes the double quotes into something that looks like double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that after the first few files I copy pasted the command on a message app (Slack was the app I was copy/pasting on) and it changed the double quotes into something that only looks like double quotes.

```
// this works
'command'
"command"
// this doesn't work
‘command’
“command”
```

And that seemed to be the issue.
Thanks to @Gyan for pointing me at the right direction!